# Placing divs left and right based on their position

Tags: html, css

i have 8 boxes generated over php on my website.

I would like to place 1st 4 of them to the left side, and last 4 to the right side, they have classes left or right depending on where they need to go.

I cannot wrap them in another element and should be done with these elements that are in code.

Any ideas?

example: https://jsfiddle.net/cembowc7/26/

```
    <div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
  left one
  </div>
    <div class="left">
  left two
  </div>
    <div class="left">
  left three
  </div>
    <div class="left">
  left four
  </div>
     <div class="right">
  right one
  </div>
    <div class="right">
  right two
  </div>
    <div class="right">
  right three
  </div>
    <div class="right">
  right four
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Generally, you would use, float: right/left. something like thi [this](https://jsfiddle.net/cembowc7/24/) might help.

Comment: used in the example. left 2 and left 4 are in the place of right 1 and right 2.

Comment: please don't edit the fiddle in the question. Post a answer or comment with it @Belder.

Answer (score 1):

```
.wrapper::after {
    display: block;
    clear: both;
    content: "";
}

.left {
    float: left;
}

.right {
    float: right;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Use float left and give width accordingly, you can also use width in pixel if you want more rigid design. I have tested the following code jsfiddle and it's working perfectly fine.

```
  wrapper{
position:relative;
width:100%;

}


.left{
 width:18%
 display:inline-block;
float:LEFT;
}

.right{
 width:18%;
FLOAT:left;
display:inline-block;
 }
```